# Displaying Lists: Collections Versus Arrays

Tags: oop, design-patterns, datamapper

In my PHP MVC application I have three main entities: Organisations, Employees and Roles.  Each Organisation has many Employees, and each Employee has a Role.

For a given Organisation, I want to display a list of Employees.  For each employee I will display name, address details, and role name.

Now, as far as I can see, the most efficient way to do this is for my service layer to return a list of employees as an array, where each element is an array of data fields (not an object).  In the mapper I would join the role table to the employee table, so the correct role name would be in the initial result set, and there would be no need to query the database again.

An alternative approach would be for my service layer to return a collection of Employee objects.  In this case, however, each Employee object would need to query the database to find the correct name for it's role (presuming the roles are lazy loaded).  This would be highly inefficient, but somehow seems more 'object oriented'.

I could consider loading the role name as a property of the Employee whenever an Employee is instantiated, however I would still need to keep a reference to the unique role ID, and so immediately I have synchronisation considerations.

What would be the typical way to solve this problem???  I am sure it has been solved millions of times!

Thanks!

Comment: A decent ORM should be able to get the information about a list of employees and their role in a single query, and retufn a list of Employee objects, each Employee having a field of type Role, containing the information about its role.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using the first alternative with objects instead of arrays. Voilá, efficient *and* object oriented.

Comment: Hi fab, how would I go about that?  Generate an Employee collection and a related Role collection at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this stuff is very standard. But I still struggle with it.

My first thought is to set up something like:

```
class Employee 
{
    protected $name; //etc

    /**
     * @var Organization
     */
    protected $organization;

    /**
     * @var Role
     */
    protected $role;

    // And then getters/setters for Role and Organization
}
```

Then an EmployeeMapper something like:

```
class EmployeeMapper
{
    /**
     * @Var DB
     */
    protectd $db;

    public function __construct(DB $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db
    }

    public function getEmployeesByOrganization($orgId)
    {
        // query here that joins employees, roles, and organizations
    }
}
```

This strikes me as clean and represents the structure you describe.

But the problem with this is that when the EmployeeMapper has to construct the Employee object,
he needs to know how the role fields and the organization fields in the joined query-results map to the fields in the Role and the Organization objects. To me, that knowledge should reside strictly within the RoleMapper and the OrganizationMapper. So maybe those mappers need to make this mapping functionality available as public methods and we need to have a way to inject RoleMapper and OrganizationMapper instances into the EmployeeMapper to use. See [Surviving The Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors#zfbook.implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors.implementation.lazy.loading.domain.objects) for a ZF-based example.

Further, it seems like sometimes - as in the "view list of employees" example you provided - you want to have information available about those attached Role and Organization entities. In that case, the overhead of joining and building the object graph is justified and (certainly better than doing separate queries-in-a-loop for roles and organizations). But in other cases, you really only want some simple employee information for a single employee like his name or his number. In this latter case, why incur the overhead of joining and building the complete object graph?

There are architectural solutions to these issues, typically using proxy objects (that stand in for the Role and Organization objects and lazy-load them when required) and custom repository objects (where you want to force the joins).

But I find architecting all this on my own to be a pain. In the end, I find that an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) has figured it all out and provides me the features described above (proxies, custom repositories, etc).